# azure service fabric vsts release (deployment) error Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Getting this error:

**Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type in the application manifest of the new application package. Please ensure that the application being upgraded has the same application type.**

[image]

My application is small and contains only 2 services. If I deploy manually from Visual Studio 2017 it's working fine. But when I deploy from a successful build in VSTS I'm getting the above error. I used the same publish profile both in manual and vsts release.

Any idea?

***Additional details from the logs:***

```html
2017-06-06T16:00:59.2449160Z ##[debug]INPUT_OVERRIDEPUBLISHPROFILESETTINGS: 'false'
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9096138Z ##[debug]Join-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code" "ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd"
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9146136Z ##[debug]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9156210Z ##[debug]Length: 94
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9166135Z ##[debug]
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9186137Z ##[debug]Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\fabric\fabric.code\ServiceFabricServiceModel.xsd"
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9216373Z ##[debug]True
2017-06-06T16:01:00.9226141Z ##[debug]
2017-06-06T16:01:03.5668693Z ##[debug]Leaving D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.9\deploy.ps1.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.5767636Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.5787644Z ##[debug]Error record:
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6307491Z ##[debug]Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type in the application manifest of the new application package. Please ensure that the application being upgraded has the same application type.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6317836Z ##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.9\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication.ps1:195 char:17
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6329753Z ##[debug]+                 throw $errMsg
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6338786Z ##[debug]+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6350377Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Application typ...plication type.:String) [], RuntimeException
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6360412Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type in the application     manifest of the new application package. Please ensure that the application being upgraded has the same applicati    on type.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6370408Z ##[debug] 
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6380417Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6410418Z ##[debug]at Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication, D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.9\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication.ps1: line 195
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6420417Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\ServiceFabricDeploy_c6650aa0-185b-11e6-a47d-df93e7a34c64\1.3.9\deploy.ps1: line 144
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6430417Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6440419Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6450418Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6460418Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6480463Z ##[debug]Exception:
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6529321Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type in the application manifest of the new application package. Please ensure that the application being upgraded has the same application type.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6825375Z ##[error]Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type in the application manifest of the new application package. Please ensure that the application being upgraded has the same application type.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6825375Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Application type of application '' doesn't match the application type in the application manifest of the new application package. Please ensure that the application being upgraded has the same application type.
2017-06-06T16:01:03.6845374Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2017-06-06T16:01:03.7105387Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application
2017-06-06T16:01:03.7155386Z ##[debug]Cleaning agent temp folder: d:\a\_temp
2017-06-06T16:01:03.7155386Z ##[section]Finishing: Release
```

Comment: have you tried deleting and unprovisioning the application on the cluster?

Comment: @EricLizotte, Yeah. I tried it now and still the same error.

Comment: What's the detail build/release log? You can share it on the OneDrive. You are using Visual Studio 2017, do you select Visual Studio 2017 for Visual Studio Build task (Visual Studio version). On the other hand, you need to use Hosted VS2017 agent if you want to use hosted agent.

Comment: @starain-MSFT, I also post issue to service fabric github https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/306. I'm using Hosted VS2017. I can share you the build logs and the artifacts.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a the new project?

Comment: Nope. New project is fine. I have 3 new asf app building and releasing properly. This one is weird. I was expecting to see an error something like this An application with name 'fabric:/{APPNAME}' already exists, its type is 'Type' and version is '1.0.0.20160812.7'. It shows the actual name. But in my case the name is ''.

Comment: @starain-MSFT How can I share only to you the all the logs. The full logs contains some information I can't show to everybody. Would you be able to message me privately?

Comment: @marvs You can remove sensitive information, then share the log files.

Comment: @starain-MSFT here's the log https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6hJfOQYu4f4WVRsZHhfcGw0RWc

Comment: Another thought, if you can compare the actual manifest of the old build vs new it would probably give more of a hint. In VSTS you'd go to the build, then artifacts, download the drop folder then compare what's in the \projectartifacts\src\something\something\PublishProfiles as well as whats in the \deploymentpackage\applicationmanifest.xml against each other.

Comment: @EricLizotte, Yep I did that. The applicationmanifest and publishprofile in the link provided above was come from vsts build artifacts that I downloaded.

Comment: It might be handy to do a diff between that and the prior one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause and it's so silly. It's really easy to missed this as you can't see the whole textbox values in vsts unless you drag your mouse up to the end. The parameters is also pointing to publish profiles which is wrong and I corrected that.

[image]